# Efficient Particle-Pair Interactions Calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, particle-system

I have an N-body simulation that generates a list of particle positions, for multiple timesteps in the simulation. For a given frame, I want to generate a list of the pairs of particles' indices `(i, j)` such that `dist(p[i], p[j]) < masking_radius`. Essentially I'm creating a list of "interaction" pairs, where the pairs are within a certain distance of each other. My current implementation looks something like this:

```
interaction_pairs = []

# going through each unique pair (order doesn't matter)
for i in range(num_particles):
    for j in range(i + 1, num_particles):
        if dist(p[i], p[j]) < masking_radius:
            interaction_pairs.append((i,j))
```

Because of the large number of particles, this process takes a long time (>1 hr per test), and it is severely limiting to what I need to do with the data. I was wondering if there was any more efficient way to structure the data such that calculating these pairs would be more efficient instead of comparing every possible combination of particles. I was looking into KDTrees, but I couldn't figure out a way to utilize them to compute this more efficiently. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are the points in 2 or 3 dimensions? If 2 you could try a variant of the "Finding the closest pair of points" algorithm given in Cormen et al.'s *Introduction to Algorithms*.

Comment: Your algorithm has time complexity `O(n**2)` while Cormen's has `O(n*log(n))`. You could also try [pypy](http://pypy.org/) which speeds up much Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using python, sklearn has multiple implementations for nearest neighbours finding:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

There is KDTree and Balltree provided.

As for KDTree the main point is to push all the particles you have into KDTree, and then for each particle ask query: "give me all particles in range X". KDtree usually do this faster than bruteforce search.
You can read more for example here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/kdtrees.pdf

If you are using 2D or 3D space, then other option is to just cut the space into big grid (which cell size of masking radius) and assign each particle into one grid cell. Then you can find possible candidates for interaction just by checking neighboring cells (but you also have to do a distance check, but for much fewer particle pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple technique using plain Python that can reduce the number of comparisons required.

We first sort the points along either the X, Y, or Z axis (selected by `axis` in the code below). Let's say we choose the X axis. Then we loop over point pairs like your code does, but when we find a pair whose distance is greater than the `masking_radius` we test whether the difference in their X coordinates is also greater than the `masking_radius`. If it is, then we can bail out of the inner `j` loop because all points with a greater `j` have a greater X coordinate.

My `dist2` function calculates the squared distance. This is faster than calculating the actual distance because computing the square root is relatively slow.

I've also included code that behaves similar to your code, i.e., it tests every pair of points, for speed comparison purposes; it also serves to check that the fast code is correct. ;)

```
from random import seed, uniform
from operator import itemgetter

seed(42)

# Make some fake data
def make_point(hi=10.0):
    return [uniform(-hi, hi) for _ in range(3)]

psize = 1000
points = [make_point() for _ in range(psize)]

masking_radius = 4.0
masking_radius2 = masking_radius ** 2

def dist2(p, q):
    return (p[0] - q[0])**2 + (p[1] - q[1])**2 + (p[2] - q[2])**2

pair_count = 0
test_count = 0

do_fast = 1
if do_fast:
    # Sort the points on one axis
    axis = 0
    points.sort(key=itemgetter(axis))

    # Fast
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        left, right = i - 1, i + 1
        for j in range(i + 1, psize):
            test_count += 1
            q = points[j]
            if dist2(p, q) < masking_radius2:
                #interaction_pairs.append((i, j))
                pair_count += 1
            elif q[axis] - p[axis] >= masking_radius:
                break

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('\r {:3} '.format(i), flush=True, end='')

    total_pairs = psize * (psize - 1) // 2
    print('\r {} / {} tests'.format(test_count, total_pairs))

else:
    # Slow
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        for j in range(i+1, psize):
            q = points[j]
            if dist2(p, q) < masking_radius2:
                #interaction_pairs.append((i, j))
                pair_count += 1

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('\r {:3} '.format(i), flush=True, end='')

print('\n', pair_count, 'pairs')
```

**output** with `do_fast = 1`

```
 181937 / 499500 tests

 13295 pairs
```

**output** with `do_fast = 0`

```
 13295 pairs
```

Of course, if most of the point pairs are within `masking_radius` of each other, there won't be much benefit in using this technique. And sorting the points adds a little bit of time, but Python's TimSort is rather efficient, especially if the data is already partially sorted, so if the `masking_radius` is sufficiently small you should see a noticeable improvement in the speed.